# How to create trigger in sql that joins 2 tables

Tags: sql

I need to create a trigger in sql that checks if the user has answered on question that related to a specific app is actually registered to that app.

The tables that I am using are:

1) **tblAnsweredOn** which contains the following columns:
email (Key), appName(key), questionNo(Key), answer, answerDate

2)**tblRegisteredTo** which contains the following columns:
email(key), appName(key), registrationDate, nickName

This is the code that i tried, but it not allows me to insert any user no matter if he is trying to answer on a question that related to an app he is registered to or not.

```
create trigger ifExistsTrigger
on [dbo].[tblAnsweredOn] after insert as
declare
@email nvarchar,
@appName nvarchar

select @email = INSERTED.email , @appName = INSERTED.AppName
from INSERTED

if not exists (select email, appName
               from [dbo].[tblRegisteredTo] 
               where email = @email
               and appName = @appName)
rollback;
```

Comment: What dbms are you using? Can you provide the DDL statements for your tables and some sample data that illustrates this problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not getting the results you expect because you are treating the `inserted` pseudo-table as a scalar instead of as a table. You can simply join `inserted` and `tblRegisteredTo` to get your results.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT email, appName
    FROM inserted A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblRegisteredTo B
    ON A.email = B.email AND A.appName = B.appName
    WHERE B.appName IS NULL OR B.email IS NULL)
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: @agni Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)